# Almost the same code but very different answers

Tags: javascript

I was writing a program in JavaScript that calculates the number of 6-digit numbers the sum of  whose first 3 digits is equal to the sum of the last 3 digits. So I wrote two different solutions to the problem although only one returns the correct answer.
Also I wrote a function `sumOfDigits()` which simply calculates the sum of digits of the number passed to it. This function is not written here but it works correct.

---

```
function count1() {
    total=0;
    for (i = 100000; i <= 999999; i+=1) {
         part = i % 1000;
         if ((sumOfDigits(i-part)) == ((sumOfDigits(part)))) {
             total+=1;
         }
     } return total;
}
```

---

```
function count2() {
    array = [];
    for (i = 100000; i <= 999999; i+=1) {
        part = i % 1000;
        if ((sumOfDigits(i-part)) == ((sumOfDigits(part)))) {
            array.push(i);
        }
    } return array;
}
```

The `count1()` function does not work correctly and returns 28 as the answer while the `count2()` function which returns an array returns an array of length 50412 which is the correct answer. Can somebody please tell me why the first function does not work correctly.

A screenshot of the `count1` function in action.
[image: A screenshot of the count1() function in action.]

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? im curious to see this in action

Comment: i'm try your `count1` function and it return `50412`, possibly in your code you have another function with name `count1`

Comment: I also tested it, and it works fine. Whatever you're doing wrong isn't in the function. Btw, go easy on the parentheses. You can just write `if (sumOfDigits(i-part) == sumOfDigits(part))`.

Comment: @MarceloCantos It aint working for me. Check the screenshot i have uploaded.

Comment: try to merge both the codes. I mean have a counter as well as an array at the same time. Then see what are the corresponding values.

Comment: You use global variables inside your functions, it is not very well :-)

Comment: I stand (self-)corrected. The problem was inside the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using `total` in the implementation of `sumOfDigits()`? I'm guessing that both functions are using the same global `total`.

You should prefix all local variables with `var` on their first use so that they aren't treated as global variables, e.g.:

```
var total = 0;
```

**EDIT:** I just confirmed this. If `sumOfDigits()` uses the global `total`, `count1()` returns 28.

Comment: Yes, now it works! But why did the var matter? Can you please edit your answer to explain that too.

Comment: @shauryagupta when you ouse global var - on every call `sumOfDigits` it change, so as result you have 9+9+9 as total and increment it, so 28

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope more abuot variables

Answer (score 1):

May be `total` is a global variable with some value on your solution. Try create another variable for return:

```
 function count1() {
        var count = 0;
        for (i = 100000; i <= 999999; i+=1) {
             part = i % 1000;
             if ((sumOfDigits(i-part)) == ((sumOfDigits(part)))) {
                 count+=1;
             }
         } return count;
    }
```

Comment: No, my code is correct because the `if` block must be true 50412 times.

Comment: `total += 1` and `array.push(i)` are called the same number of times, so `total` should equal `array.length`.

Comment: @shauryagupta, possibly in your code you have another function with name `count1` that return another value?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could reconsider your code. Here is a simpler and faster approach (<500ms in nodejs, faster because it's all numbers, i.e. no conversions):

```
//helper: sum of digits in number [n]
function sumOfDigits(n){
   if (!(n^0) || n<10) {return n;}
   var sum = 0;
   while (n>=10) {
     sum += n%10;
     n = (n/10)^0;
   }
   return sum+n;
}

function sumDigitsComparer(num){
  return  sumOfDigits((num/1000)^0) === sumOfDigits(num%1000);
}

var x = 1000000, n = 0;
while ((x-=1,x>=100000)) { sumDigitsComparer(x) && (n+=1); }
//=> n = 50412
```